# Getting multiple elements: only return the last one

Tags: javascript, html, forms, get

I'm trying to get multiple elements (input) through a function via className and element name but in both cases only return the last element. Even though I clicked the first two checkboxs the alert is "bye is false". This should show like "true" the element at the moment when I clicked on it, but doesn't happen.

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="checkbox" name="inPut" value="hi" class="greeting" /> Hi!!
  </br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="inPut" value="good" class="greeting" /> Good Morning!!
  </br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="inPut" value="bye" class="greeting" /> Bye!!
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to get them using classNAME:

```
var inNer = document.getElementsByClassName('greeting');


    for (var i = 0; i < inNer.length; i++){

        prueba = inNer[i];
        var test = prueba.onclick = showIn;

      }


    function showIn(){

      var rex = prueba;
      alert('\''+rex.value+'\'' + ' es ' + rex.checked);
    }
```

And I tried get the elements through Name:

```
var inName = document.box.inPut;


for (var i = 0; i < inName.length; i++){

  var test = inName[i];
  var call = test.onclick = showIn;
}

function showIn(){

  var outPut = test;
  alert(outPut.value + ' is ' + outPut.checked);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `showIn` function is incorrect. There's no need to assign `prueba` again. It should be:

```
function showIn() {
  alert('\'' + this.value + '\'' + ' es ' + this.checked);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/88URU/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var inNer = document.getElementsByClassName('greeting');
for(var i=0; i<inNer.length; i++){
   inNer[i].onclick = showIn;
}
function showIn(){
   alert(this.value +" es "+ this.checked);
}
```

btw, `</br>` should be `<br>` || `<br />` || `<br/>` just not `</br>`